# How can I get TermStoreIds and TermSetIds from the MMS?

Tags: mms, managed-metadata-service

If I go to the Term Store Management Tool there is a tsid in the query string, but this value does not seem to change.  Is there an easy way to get TermStoreIds and TermSetIds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word: PowerShell

Check google or start here http://get-spscripts.com/2010/06/create-new-term-with-synonym-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way (at least in SharePoint 2013) is in the Term Store Management Tool there is a `Unique Identifier` section with the TermStoreId or the TermSetId depending on what is selected.